# How do I fix the output on my external displays?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11, external-display

I'm trying to hook up a monitor to my laptop (extend mode). However, the display stream is quite deformed:

[image: like this]

The resolution matches the monitor's native resolution. I have tried everything in Windows' own built-in Display Settings, but they weren't much help. How can I fix this display issue?

Comment: While we cannot help you with 3rd party applications, your issue may be related to a monitor setting called [overscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2Ei.png). You should be able to access the monitor's OSD menu using the physical control buttons found on the front/back/or bottom edge of the monitor.

Comment: the picture shows the image extending past the bottom of the monitor

Comment: @jsotola Which is intended. A part of the bottom is cut off in my external display (I cannot see the taskbar).

Comment: it looks like Windows is configured for a 2x3 display instead of 3x2 ... the horizontal and vertical resolutions may be swapped somehow ... does the monitor rotate between landscape and portrait modes?

Comment: (1) Please don’t post an image that is a grotesque fabrication.  I don’t believe that any sort of ordinary monitor would be able to display an image outside the physical dimensions of the display screen.  (2) Your illustration *doesn’t **illustrate*** the problem, since we don’t know what the image is supposed to look like.  *Explain* what wrong (in words).  (3) It *might* help if you mentioned identified the external monitor (brand / model). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.